# C++: Convert value int (For example: 0x00AAFAD8) to pointer (Also the pointer itself is the 0x00AAFAD8 value)

Tags: c++

i want to Convert value int (For example: 0x00AAFAD8) to pointer (Also the pointer itself is the 0x00AAFAD8 value). I don't know how it's called, so i want help for manage memory spaces by values like this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is dangerous territory, but you simply need `MyType * = static_cast<MyType *>(MyInt)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pointer address this way:

```
int i = 0x00AAFAD8;
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(i);
```

Comment: I mean, i is not valued int i = 0x00AAFAD8, i want to access the memory space that is 0x00AAFAD8, but it's value is for example (i=4, and memory space or pointer is 0x00AAFAD8)... and access it as int len(int ln) where ln is the integer 0x00AAFAD8. 

Trying to access as unsigned char* ln1 = (unsigned char*) ln.